# Python Dictionary to Json with dataframe.to_json as values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert dictionary to json, and one of dictionary values is from dataframe.to_json, and I got some strange output as following:

Here is the code

```
import json
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {}

my_dict["ClassName"] = "First class"
# get student list
df = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")
my_dict["StudentList"] = df.to_json(orient='records')

# output
with open("./output.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(my_dict, fp, indent=4)
```

Here is the input file ./test.csv

```
Name,Age
Joe,20
Emily,22
John,21
Peter,23
```

Here is the output file ./output.json

```
{
    "ClassName": "First class",
    "StudentList": "[{\"Name\":\"Joe\",\"Age\":20},{\"Name\":\"Emily\",\"Age\":22},{\"Name\":\"John\",\"Age\":21},{\"Name\":\"Peter\",\"Age\":23}]"
}
```

Here is what I need:

```
{
    "ClassName": "First class",
    "StudentList": [{"Name":"Joe","Age":20},{"Name":"Emily","Age":22},{"Name":"John","Age":21},{"Name":"Peter","Age":23}]
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.to_dict` instead of `df.to_json`:

```
my_dict["StudentList"] = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

`to_json` just returns a string representation of the JSON, while `to_dict` returns an actual JSON object.